# Python regular expression, remove repeated class

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of timestamp strings. Each string has three sections and delimiters between sections. A delimiter may be any of these [.:,;] symbols. Each section contains digits. The first one may contain one or two digits. Any other section may contain two digits. I need to retrieve those digits and fulfil some actions with them. I use Python3.

So I write this code:

```
import re
lines = ('1:24.15', '17.01.01', '05:07:28', '175.11.123', '4:35,07', '01;21;73', '00;1;1', '7;7.12')
pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d{1,2})[:.,;](\d{2})[:.,;](\d{2})$')
for i in lines:
    try:
        mm, ss, ff = pattern.search(i).groups()
    except AttributeError:
        print('{} is invalid'.format(i))
    print(int(mm) * 60 + int(ss) + round(int(ff) / 0.075 / 1000, 3))
```

My question is... How could I reduce the repetitions in this regular expression?

```
r'^(\d{1,2})[:.,;](\d{2})[:.,;](\d{2})$'
```

Thank you in advance. I'll be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[.:;,]")
for line in lines:
    mm, ss, ff = pattern.split(line)
```

Though, this would require an additional length check of `mm`, `ss` and `ff`. On one hand - this makes things less attractive, but this leads to *more precise and meaningful error messages*:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[.:;,]")
for line in lines:
    try:
        mm, ss, ff = pattern.split(line)
    except ValueError:
        print('{} has not enough digit groups'.format(line))
        continue

    if len(mm) not in (1, 2) or len(ss) != 2 or len(ff) != 2:
        print('{} has a digit group with invalid length'.format(line))
        continue

    print(int(mm) * 60 + int(ss) + round(int(ff) / 0.075 / 1000, 3))
```

Comment: @AndreyMylnikov sure, catch the `ValueError` exception.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand how. An example would be wonderful... :)

Comment: @AndreyMylnikov sure, it is basically the same as in the code provided by you, just replace `AttributeError` with `ValueError`.

Comment: Does not work... The line '175.11.123' is invalid. But Python prints it. I need it to be sorted out and marked as invalid. Look at my example. The bad lines marked as invalid.

Comment: @AndreyMylnikov okay, sure, updated. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`r'^(\d{1,2})([:.,;](\d{2})){2}$'`

That should be as compact as it can go.